# cannot remove $HADOOP_PREFIX from .bashrc which gives error in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I  have installed hadoop using tar files. i have added $HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop in the .bashrc file . everything was working fine. Now , i installed Hadoop using Horton's Ambari. I have removed the  previous hadoop environment variable $HADOOP_PREFIX from all the system   from .bashrc file.
Now when i give the command   `echo $HADOOP_PREFIX`  it is still showing the old path /usr/local/hadoop . Is there any way to remove that variable.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the $HADOOP_PREFIX from .bahrc file then run this command

```
unset HADOOP_PREFIX
```

Comment: Thanks it worked .  one more thing , if we just run the unset command , wihtout deleting the variable from .bashrc, will it remain unset for that particular bash session.??